# How do I obtain the DRM security level supported by a device?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I tried to connect my app to HUAWEI WisePlay DRM. I wanted to know the DRM security level supported by a user's phone so that I could apply the most secure DRM solution to the phone. However, I didn't know how to obtain the DRM security level. I tried to find the answer in the development guide on HUAWEI Developers, but didn't find anything helpful. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the public String getPropertyString (String propertyName) API of the MediaDrm class to obtain the value of the securityLevel attribute indicating the WisePlay DRM security level. The options are SW (software level), HW (hardware level), and EH (enhanced hardware level).